# How to use parameters on gradlew Android terminal?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to publish to a Maven repository through the terminal on Android Studio by passing parameters. Currently I've been doing so by using the following command, which calls three tasks with configuration written on my build.gradle.

```
gradlew assembleRelease generatePomFileForAarPublication artifactoryPublish
```

How I have configured my gradle to publish to Maven:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId packageName
            version = libraryVersion
            artifactId project.getName()
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")

            pom.withXml {
                def dependencies = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.getByName("releaseCompileClasspath").getResolvedConfiguration().getFirstLevelModuleDependencies().each {
                    def dependency = dependencies.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependency.appendNode('groupId', it.moduleGroup)
                    dependency.appendNode('artifactId', it.moduleName)
                    dependency.appendNode('version', it.moduleVersion)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is through the terminal pass as parameter the variables **packageName** and **libraryVersion**. Is this possible?